# Entity Framework Linq Query to return list of IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

How do I get a list of companyIDs who shipped all their orders in linq?
Scenario: Each company got a bunch of customers and orders for customers. Here from the below tables, CompanyB and CompanyC has shipped all the orders to customers and I want to get those ID from a linq query.

3 tables involved Company, Customers and Orders

```
Company
CompanyID CompanyName
   1         CompanyA
   2         CompnayB
   3         CompnayC

Customers
CustomerID CustomerName   CompanyID
   1         CustomerA      1
   2         CustomerB      2
   3         CustomerC      2
   4         CustomerD      2
   5         CustomerE      1
   6         CustomerF      2
   7         CustomerG      3


Orders
OrderID  CustomerID  Shipped
  1         2           1
  2         3           1
  3         4           1
  4         6           1
  5         1           0
  6         7           1
```

Here is what I tried and I'm not getting the right output

```
var IDs = Company.Where(co => co.Customers.Any(cu => cu.Orders.Any(o => o.shipped))).ToList();
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a sample answer to go with your sample data... and said what was wrong with your attempted query... PS the word all might be a clue to what's wrong with your query.

Comment: You might be missing a select clause since you only need the IDs. Could you post what your entity models look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var IDs =  (from co in Company
             join cu in Customers on co.CompanyID equals cu.CompanyID
             join o in Orders on cu.CustomerID  equals o.CustomerID
             where o.Shipped
             select new { co.CompanyID }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you miss the condition of companies who shipped all orders .

Comment: great, I voted up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running this, but what if I try `All` instead of `Any`? Probably, if you are working with a database on EF and not just a collection, you should have *lazy loading* enabled.
And, since you only need the `ID`, I added `Select`

```
var IDs = Company
    .Where(co => co.Customers.All(cu => cu.Orders.All(o => o.Shipped)))
    .Select(co => co.CompanyID)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join two tables with linq like below :

```
var Ids = (from cu in Customers
          join o in Orders on cu.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
          where o.Shipped
          select cu.CompanyId).Distinct().ToList();
```

and you can use fluentApi :

```
var ids = Orders.Where(o => o.Shipped).Join(Customers, o => o.CustomerId, c => c.CustomerId, (o, c) => new
{
    c.CompanyId
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on `SelectMany` as an alternative to double `All` calls:

```cs
var companyIds = Companies
    .Where(co => co.Customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders).All(o => o.shipped))
    .Select(co => co.CompanyId)
    .ToList();
```

This feels slightly more semantic IMHO for your requirement.